# How to cope with many languages at the same time

Tags: psycholinguistics, multilingualism

I am a student who knows English, and whose mother tongue is Russian. I started studying English around 15 years ago and never put any effort into it. I just grew organically and managed to get to academic IELTS 7.5 4 years ago. Since that time my skills have only improved. But now I need to study 1 more language - Finnish, which seems to be a total nightmare (in comparison to English - but its only my personal feeling about it).

Now I have started noticing that when I learn Finnish too much on one day, I start forgetting English words. If I switch to English, I do cope well, but sometimes words just slip away from my mind. On the other hand, Finnish words in my mind mingle with the words from Russian and English. And now the questions are:

1) Is it possible to forget a language if one already has proficiency in it at around level B2-C1?

2) How many languages is it possible to learn and maintain at level B2-C1, because in the long term I would also like to learn German and Japanese (probably next 10 years), and I do not want to forget other languages I know.

3) Are there any special exercises or activities employed by multilingual people to maintain their skills at decent level?

4) How much time a week is required to support 1 language which is already at the level mentioned above?

5) How many languages an average person can maintain at level B2-C1 simultaneously?

PS. Sorry if the question is too broad. It is just my curiosity. But I suppose that this place is the right place to ask it.

Comment: Too many questions! Ask them one at a time please.

Comment: For the record, I've had very similar experiences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) It is possible to lose proficiency in any language if not used. This may take many forms from total loss to reduced vocabulary or just decreased fluency.

2) & 5) There's no hard limit to the number of languages one can acquire. For example, many historians will learn 4 or 5 languages at quite high level to be able to read sources. For conversation, the limit is set more by opportunities and need to use the language. Learning and maintaining a language is a fairly labor-intensive and time-consuming but there doesn't seem to be a limit in terms of brain or memory limitations. Your goal of English, Finish and German is not all that extreme.

3) There are many strategies polyglots use. I'd recommend watching interviews with polyglots on YouTube. Like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CBlMYYf8Uk. Many of these were collected in the book 'Babel no More' (http://www.babelnomore.com). You can also read the Benny Lewis' blog entries on http://www.fluentin3months.com/blog. Using his methods is a plausible way to achieve proficiency but requires high commitment.

4) There's no set time. Once you achieve that level of proficiency, you don't need to maintain the languages so hard. Just make sure you read, listen, write and speak in each language once in a while. However, you will have to work very hard to get to that level. Still, you will have to discover how much time works for you.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Great links.